# key not found error

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence

I have a dimension called customer, with UnknowMember = True  and UnknowMemberName = NA. When I process my dimension, I see all my customers plus a NA member. I also configured ErrorConfiguration = IgnoreError and KeyErrorLimit = 100

I have a row on my fact with NULL on the customerID and the Cube fails to process with this error  (its changing NULL to 0, not sure if it is expected):

```
Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_FactSales', Column: 'CustomerId', Value: '0'. The attribute is 'Customer'.
```

I was expecting that, based on my configuration of the dimension, that the NULL row would be assigned to the NA member of the dimension.

What am I missing? Is it possible to be done?

FYI: I know that I could have a Unknow record on my db and deal with it on the ETL process, but I would like SSAS to handle this situation.

Comment: which version of SSAS are you using?

Comment: also, are you sure you don't have more than 100 records in your source with missing key values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey lads thanks for the help.
the problem was that I was doing these configurations at the dimension. I should have done in the Measure group.