# Error while processing the cube

Tags: ssas

I 've a cube that I can always successfully deploy it. But I 've mistakenly deleted it from ssas .Now I can't deployed it .
How can I deploy it again ?Igot always the following error .

> Key attribute not found when processing: Table: , Column:'', Value:''.
>   The attribute is''. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute
>   key was converted to an unknown member because the latter is found.
>   Job attribute of the dimension Dim Job of the database:, Cube, Measure
>   Group:, Partition: Fact Amount, Recording: 640 Errors in the OLAP
>   storage engine:. Processing operation ended because the number of
>   errors that occurred during the operation has reached the limit of
>   permissible errors. Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error
>   occurred during the processing of the'' partition of the measure group
>   for the'' cube'' from the database.

[image]

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974559/ssas-attribute-key-cannot-be-found-even-though-it-exists-and-is-not-due-to-dupli#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error states that the fact table contains a foreign key value that is not found in the dimension table. And it states the referenced attribute and the exact value as well.

Correct your relational data, and the cube should process fine again.